# Concern about having lots of redux-aware components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm currently writing a component for comments that is Redux-aware and stateless. My concern is that if say each comment is connected to a user-post, and say there are 100 posts, will that slow down my app?

So for example.

```
class Comments extends Component {
  doThis() {
    const props = this.props;
    props.dispatch(someAction(props.data.id));
  }
  render(){
    <Button onPress={()=> this.doThis()}
  }
}

export default connect()(Comments);
```

Then in some other component:

```
arr.map((item) => {
  return <Comment data={item} /> 
})
```

Is this the proper way to use Redux?

Comment: Your explanation is rather vague and the example you've provided is confusing. However, since you don't know what will slow down your app until you write it and stress test it out on real world data I'd say not to get bogged down on performance issues now. 100 posts isn't a lot anyway. Also, I'd suggest you build out your app incrementally.

Comment: Start with internal state (using setState) and if you start to feel the pain that Redux is intended to solve then add it to your project. Only add stuff to your project if there is a real need. Of course if your intention is to learn Redux then by all means go ahead and start off with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, having more connected components leads to better performance, as each component will only re-render when the data it needs changes.  The cost of having to notify more subscribers to the Redux store is usually less than the cost of "wasted" re-renders by your components.

For more information, see:

- My blog post [Practical Redux, Part 6: Connected Lists, Forms, and Performance](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/)
- the [Redux FAQ on performance and scaling](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-scaling)
- the [Redux FAQ on connecting multiple components](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-multiple-components)
- a [chat log where I describe the benefits of connecting each item in a large list](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/53735e4eb151bc228d6685eab00f5f85)
- and the [Redux Performance](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#redux-performance) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).